Can I use Ulalek's ability multiple times after casting a single spell?
So my friends and I were talking about Ulalek, Fused Atrocity, the new Commander for the Eldrazi pre-con deck, and I wanted to know if the ability can be paid for more than once on just any instance. For example if I was to cast Ulamog, which has a cast trigger, could I pay two colorless however many times I want to trigger the same cast trigger or is it once per cast?

This is slightly tangential to your question, but copying a spell will not trigger any on-cast triggered abilities again, since you don't cast the copy.

@MatthewJensen Ulalek does copy triggers on the stack in addition to spells, so the on cast triggers will still get an additional. copy put on stack.

Extort would be OP if this were how it worked.

@Andrew Yes, but the copy of the trigger is from Ulalek. The copy doesn't put additional triggers on the stck.

You can pay once for each spell you cast.
Ulalek's ability is a triggered ability. When you cast an Eldrazi spell, the ability goes on the stack. Once the ability resolves, it gives you one opportunity to pay {C}{C}, and if you do, it copies each other spell and ability on the stack once.

You would need Echoes of Eternity out to do what you are asking. That would make a loop with Ulalek to pay for his ability as many times as you can afford it. You could also add things like Annie Joins Up, Strionic Resonator, or Roaming Throne to double up on his ability while still having to pay the two colorless for each time the trigger is doubled
